# Using 7zip Delphi wrapper from C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, wrapper, c++builder, 7zip

I'm trying to utilize "7za.dll" together with this Delphi wrapper - http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=13

Having difficulties translating this code to C++ and understanding the wrapper itself:

```
procedure TMainForm.ExtractAllClick(Sender: TObject);
  var Arch: I7zOutArchive;
begin
  Arch := CreateOutArchive(CLSID_CFormat7z);
  // add a file
  Arch.AddFile('c:\test.bin', 'folder\test.bin');
  // add files using willcards and recursive search
  Arch.AddFiles('c:\test', 'folder', '*.pas;*.dfm', true);
  // add a stream
  Arch.AddStream(aStream, soReference, faArchive, CurrentFileTime, CurrentFileTime, 'folder\test.bin', false, false);
  // compression level
  SetCompressionLevel(Arch, 5);
  // compression method if <> LZMA
  SevenZipSetCompressionMethod(Arch, m7BZip2);
  // add a progress bar ...
  Arch.SetProgressCallback(...);
  // set a password if necessary
  Arch.SetPassword('password');
  // Save to file
  Arch.SaveToFile('c:\test.zip');
  // or a stream
  Arch.SaveToStream(aStream);
end;
```

I've made additional wrapper of wrapper Delphi unit which when included in C++ code wraps above and it works. Now I'd like to use it a step further - call the above in C++ code directly.

How do I initialize, construct and release this `I7zOutArchive` interface properly in C++?

Is there a need to destroy (free memory) in above code or is it automatic when it goes out of scope (I usually use `boost::scoped_ptr` to do the job, is something like that required here)?

Comment: Isn't that going to be a C++ wrapper of a Delphi wrapper of C++ code? Why don't you use the 7zip C++ SDK?

Comment: I know, it is not ideal. But the speed is not an issue and I did search and couldn't find some decent docs simple example I could use in C++ Builder (they are all for Visual Studio). The COM interface 7za.dll uses is not standard Windows COM but somewhat different. If you have a short example that basically does the above, I would more than grateful to learn new things but for now this works.

Comment: Speed wasn't the issue I had in mind. Just the clunkiness of it. Don't see why the VS examples wouldn't work in C++ Builder. Anyway, that was just my thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to destroy the thing returned by `CreateOutArchive`, but `scoped_ptr` would be inappropriate. Instead, use the built-in [`System::DelphiInterface`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.DelphiInterface) class:

```
System::DelphiInterface<I7zOutArchive> Arch = CreateOutArchive(CLSID_CFormat7z);
```

Then, call methods on that object the same as you would any other COM interface. (Replace Delphi's `.` operator with `->`, and you're most of the way there.) The object will get destroyed when the reference count reaches zero, which generally occurs when `Arch` goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, everything works and debugger also says module unload for 7za.dll on function exit so I guess everything is cleaned up, just a small typo it is Interface not Iterface :)